# Python regex match broblem

Tags: python, regex

So I've got this little code:

```
import re
file = open('frame.txt',"r")


for i in file:
    a = re.match(r"/\*(.*)/g",i)
    print a
```

Which prints "None" for each line besides at http://www.regexr.com/ matching is correct but I'm expecting a match

lorem *** wew**

ispum *** ewew**

dolor *** wew**

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What did you expect to see, and what did you actually see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.regexr.com/ is designed for javascript and follows the Javascript regex syntax. But Python do not need delimiters (remove the slashes) and the g modifier must be replaced by the appropriate method (probably `re.findall`)

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more informations.

https://pythex.org/ is an online tester specially designed for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing (because of lack of info) that the "/g" should not be part of your reg ex.
It should be given as a flag, as the re.match API is:

```
match(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

Since you probably copied from http://www.regexr.com/, I guess you don't need the flag anyway.
After removing the "/g" you'll get your matches.
Remember you will get Match objects (you can see the string you caught with MatchObject.string.

Anyway, if it is not a huge file, you can use re.findall():

```
file = open('frame.txt',"r")
content = file.read()
matches = re.findall(r"/\*(.*)", content)
```